# Adding and removing classes not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've used this exact code on a different div element and it works perfectly. When I went to add the same code to another div element with a different id it registers the element has been clicked but it doesn't add or remove any of the classes.

```
$('#quoteClick').click(function(){
    $('#cbox-1').addClass('displayCboxBackground');
    $('#cbox-2').removeClass('displayCboxBackground');
    $('#cbox-3').removeClass('displayCboxBackground');

    $('#dbox-1').addClass('displayBlock');
    $('#dbox-2').removeClass('displayBlock');
    $('#dbox-3').removeClass('displayBlock');
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

The html structure is as follows:

```
<div id="cbox-1">
    <div id="dbox-1">
         content...
    </div>
</div>    
<div id="cbox-2">
    <div id="dbox-2">
         content...
    </div>
</div>
<div id="cbox-3">
    <div id="dbox-3">
         <div id="quoteClick">
             a quote
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m81c23cx/1/

In the fiddle you can see the content will changes when each header is clicked. When the "quoteClick" element is clicked I want it to change to the second headers content exactly how it does when the second header is clicked.

I can see in Chrome's console that when I click the div element that it highlights all the classes but it doesn't change any of them.  I have the jQuery inside a `document.ready()` function so it should be waiting for the DOM to load and it works perfectly when I just write the lines into the console.

Comment: Are you getting the `clicked` text in console when you click the button?

Comment: Could you please provide us your HTML too

Comment: You can also provide a JSFiddle where the problem  can be reproduced.

Comment: Are you sure you  don't have multiple elements with the same id?

Comment: Provide your snippet or fiddle then its simple to resolve

Comment: As @pictoru suggests check duplicated IDs

Comment: If quoteAdvert added dynamically?

Comment: Clicked does appear in the console, I don't have multiple elements with the same id and quoteAdvert is static. I've never used fiddle but i'll give it a go now!

Comment: Also turn off any **AdBlocker** given the ID of the element

Comment: I tried with adblocker disabled and changed the name of the element.  I also managed to reproduce it on a fiddle.

Comment: In your jsfiddle, you use the jquery selector $('#quoteClick') but there is no element with that id. There is a #quoteAdvert element. Change that and you'll see the click in the console.

Comment: Sorry my copy and pasting mistake. I've fixed it in the fiddle, and the issue still exists. So the console will say the element has been clicked but it doesn't add and remove the classes to the other properties.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that nobody actually questioned your use of ids (instead of suggesting that you should double-check for dupes). The reason why this code is hard to debug is because it's too complicated. As a result, you'll have a hard time fixing issues similar to this in the future too.

Drop it, do it better.
I didn't even go through your fiddle. Instead, I'm going to propose that you change your approach altogether.

Update your HTML and use classes instead of ids. Something similar to this:

```
<div class="cbox">
    <div class="dbox">
         content...
    </div>
</div>    
<div class="cbox">
    <div class="dbox">
         content...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cbox">
    <div class="dbox">
         <div id="quoteAdvert">
             a quote
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update your JavaScript and use `this` to get the context of the current box:

```
$('.cbox').click( function cboxClicked () {
  // Remove the previous class from all .cbox & .dbox elements; we don't care which
  $('.cbox').removeClass('displayCboxBackground') 
  $('.dbox').removeClass('displayBlock')

  // Add a new class to the clicked .cbox & it's child .dbox
  $(this).addClass('displayCboxBackground')
  $(this).children('.dbox').addClass('displayBlock')
})
```

The beauty of this? You can have 1000 boxes, it'll still work. No need to add any extra lines of code.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dx6rsvsL/1/) showing it in action.

Comment: Suggestions for duplicates were before any fiddle link appeared in the question. Your solution is right, the beauty of codes matters and simplicity should rule any JS file, otherwise becomes trash. And anyway, in the fiddle, things are happening right, I think, but there is no CSS class `displayCboxBackground` in the CSS file, so nothing happen, just move the class from an element to another.

Answer (score 1):

The example code you provided is not consistent with the jsfiddle you created.

In your fiddle, you use the jquery selector `$('#quoteClick')` but there is no element with that id. There is a #quoteAdvert element however. Change that and you'll see the click in the console.

Comment: I changed the name of the id because someone suggested it might of been caused due to an adblocker blocking some interaction, sorry for the inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

The classList property returns a token list of the class attribute of the element in question. Luckily for us, it also comes with a few handy methods:

- add - adds a class
- remove - removes a class
- toggle - toggles a class
- contains - checks if a class exists

  // adds class "foo" to el
  el.classList.add("foo");

  // removes class "bar" from el
  el.classList.remove("bar");

  // toggles the class "foo"
  el.classList.toggle("foo");

  // outputs "true" to console if el contains "foo", "false" if not
  console.log( el.classList.contains("foo") );

  // add multiple classes to el
  el.classList.add( "foo", "bar" );